# Invalid `path`. Must be either string or array mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am writing the code using node.js and mongoose, I am stucked in the issue of posting the materials, where material is my entity.

Following is the schema:

```
new Schema({
            title: {
                type: String,
                trim: true,
                set: util.ucfirst,
                required: true
            },
            description: {
                type: String,
                required: true,
                trim: true
            },
            downloads:{
                type: Array,
                default: [],
                required: true
            },
            course_id: {
                type: String,
                required: false
            },
            _status: {
                required: false,
                default: true,
                type: Boolean,
                select: false
            },
            created_by:{
                type: String
            },
            created_at:{
                type: Date,
                default: Date.now
            },
            modified_by:{
                type: String
            },
            modified_at:{
                type: Date,
                default: Date.now
            }
        },
        {
            collection: collection,
            versionKey: true,
            strict: true
        })
```

Now using this data I am posting the sample data which accepts 2 "string" and 1 or more "file" data.

Following is the post api call:

```
exports.post('/', function(req,res,next){ 
    var _error = req.mydata.get('error');
    if( !_error ){
        var _object = req.mydata.get('data') || {},
            _files = req.mydata.get('files');       
        _object.downloads = (_files && Array.isArray(_files['upload'])) ? _files['upload'] : (_files && typeof _files['upload'] == "object") ? [_files['upload']] : []; 
        model.insert(_module, _object, function(err, entry){
            if( !err && entry ){
                res.status(200).json(entry);
                res.end();
            }else{
                next();
            }
        });
    }else{
        next(_error);
    }
});
```

But what I am receiving is the following output, which is not expected.
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've just run into the same problem. You can't set `versionKey` to `true`, Mongoose thinks it's a new name for the version key - which should be a string. Just omit the `versionKey` parameter and you'll be fine.

I've opened an issue for this: https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/3747